# Angular with Docker and docker-compose: The local host page cannot be found

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can run my angular app locally. However when I attempt to run it using docker I get 'The local host page cannot be found' (Side note: I have a few different services set up in the docker- compose that I have not included below).

Here is my set up:

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'
services:

shopfrontspa:
container_name: lost_chapters_shop_front
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}shopfrontspa
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: FrontEnds/ShopFrontSpa/Dockerfile
networks:
 - lost_chapters_network
```

Docker-compose.overirde:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
shopfrontspa:
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
ports:
  - "5110:80"
  - "7110:443"
volumes:
  - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
  - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

networks:
lost_chapters_network:
 external: true
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FrontEnds/ShopFrontSpa/ShopFrontSpa.csproj", "FrontEnds/ShopFrontSpa/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FrontEnds/ShopFrontSpa/ShopFrontSpa.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FrontEnds/ShopFrontSpa"
RUN dotnet build "ShopFrontSpa.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ShopFrontSpa.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShopFrontSpa.dll"]
```

Package.json:

```
 "name": "shopfrontspa",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
"start": "run-script-os",
//"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
"start:windows": "ng serve --port 44436 --ssl --ssl-cert 
%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key 
%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
"start:default": "ng serve --port 44436 --ssl --ssl-cert 
$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key 
$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
"build": "ng build",
"build:ssr": "ng run ShopFrontSpa:server:dev",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test"
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true; });
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IOrderService, OrderService>(p =>
{
    //p.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["MicroservicAddress:ApiGatewayForWeb:Uri"]);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
// Here we add Angular default Antiforgery cookie name on first load. https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection
// This cookie will be read by Angular app and its value will be sent back to the application as the header configured in .AddAntiforgery()
//app.Use((context, next) =>
//{
//    string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
//    //Do work that does not write to the Response
//    return next(context);
//    //Do logging or other work that does not write to the Response.
//});

var pathBase = app.Configuration["PATH_BASE"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathBase))
{
    app.UsePathBase(pathBase);
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    
});

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

// Handles all still unnatended (by any other middleware) requests by returning the default page of the SPA (wwwroot/index.html).
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    // the root of the angular app. (Where the package.json lives)
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "Client";

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {

        // use the SpaServices extension method for angular, that will make the application to run "ng serve" for us, when in development.
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});

app.Run();
```

Here are the log files that show it is working:

```
2023-05-02 13:06:04 warn: 

Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2023-05-02 13:06:04       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2023-05-02 13:06:04 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2023-05-02 13:06:04       No XML encryptor configured. Key {47f19310-8c91-40f1-a9a1-8599d772d586} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2023-05-02 13:06:04 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-05-02 13:06:04       Now listening on: https://[::]:443
2023-05-02 13:06:04 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-05-02 13:06:04       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-05-02 13:06:04 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-05-02 13:06:04       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-05-02 13:06:04 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-05-02 13:06:04       Hosting environment: Development
2023-05-02 13:06:04 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-05-02 13:06:04       Content root path: /app/
2023-05-02 13:19:29 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2023-05-02 13:19:29       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2023-05-02 13:19:29 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-05-02 13:19:29       Now listening on: https://[::]:443
2023-05-02 13:19:29 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-05-02 13:19:29       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-05-02 13:19:29 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-05-02 13:19:29       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-05-02 13:19:29 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-05-02 13:19:29       Hosting environment: Development
2023-05-02 13:19:29 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-05-02 13:19:29       Content root path: /app/
```

Can anyone highlight why I am having this issue?